# How do I create Payout Object in Stripe using only customer ID?

Tags: javascript, php, payment, payout

Please,help me with an issue.
I get a token from javascript (using stripe.js) and pass it to my php script to create a customer :

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "description" => "Customer for blah-blah-blah",
                "source" => $post['token_id']
            ));
```

Then I create the bank account using that created customer:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
        $bank_account = $customer->sources->create(array(
            "bank_account" => array(
                "country" => "US",
                "currency" => "usd",
                "account_holder_name" => $post['account_name'],
                "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
                "routing_number" => $post['routing_number'],
                "account_number" => $post['account_number']
            )
        ));
```

Now I need to create a Payout but only using customer ID. I've tried like this:

```
$payout = $customer->sources->create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => $currency,
        'customer' => $customerId,
    ));
```

But that's not working. 
Now I make payments via \Stripe\Charge :

```
$payout = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => $currency,
        "customer" => $customer
    ));
```

Please,can you tell me,is there any way to not use \Stripe\Charge and make a Payout only using customer ID ?
Thank you a lot !

Comment: Hey, You just need to read stripe api library And use it

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your advice. I posted this question here only because I couldn't find the answer in documentation. I thought there'll be a way that isn't described in docs.

Comment: ok give me some time to prepare a code for you. :)

Comment: I will be very grateful:) Thank You !